# Proof semidecidable languages

Tags: computation-theory, turing-machines, automaton

I have to proof "Semidecidable languages are closed by the direct morphism operation"

I think that a direct morphism from E to F is a pair of morphisms s: E -> F, p: F->E, with p · s = IdE.

So my porposal is make a proof with Turing Machines because Turing-Recognizable languages are closed under ∪, °, *, and ∩ but i dont know how to proof it with a specific language that runs in the TM (if my proposal is correct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your language L is semidecidable, there exists a Turing Machine TML that stops on every input that is in E. You want a machine TMK for the language K = s(L).

1. On input w\in F* compute v = p(w) which is in E*.
2. Simulate TML(v). If w\in s(L) then v\in L and the machine accepts.

Comment: I want to understand why you suppose that there is a Turing Machine TML (that accepts semidecidable languages) that stops on every input that is in E, and why this is a proof, i can't see it... so i will be so glad if can you explain your answer more in detail, please.

Comment: The definition of semidecidable is that there exists a TM that stops on all the inputs that are accepted, so you can suppose its existence. And the algorithm provides such a machine for s(L), which shows that also s(L) fulfills the definition of semidecidable.